# What is the best practice for implementing tags with Neo4j and rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, neo4j

Have a neo4j based rails app and want to implement tags.  Not sure how to go about it.  Was thinking of creating a new model for nodes with a "Tag" label, but that seemed kind of overkill.  Is there any approach like https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on for a Neo4j based app?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to do any on performance considerations ;)

Creating a `Tag` model isn't too overkill, especially you make sure to `merge` your tags whenever you create them to make sure you don't create duplicates.  Then you can use Neo4j's graph traversal abilities to jump from tags to other objects and vice versa, as well as do more complicated queries like making recommendations between objects according to how many tags they share / don't share.

If you just want to have a basic list of strings, Neo4j actually supports having array properties on nodes and relationships.  You can use this simply by declaring a property on your model like this:

```
class ModelClass
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode

  property :tags
end
```

The only issue is that you can't index based on arrays (I think that's planned for the future).  So if performance is a big concern rather than just showing the list of tags, then `Tag` nodes might be your best bet.

Also, to get the best performance in case you get a lot of tags, you'll want to index the tag name/text/whatever-you-call-that-property.  There are a few ways to do that:

```
class Tag
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode

  property :name, index: :exact
end
```

Or you can use a Neo4j constraint to ensure that no two nodes have the same name:

```
class Tag
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode

  property :name, constraint: :unique
end
```

Constraints automatically create indexes under the cover for performance.

Lastly, if you'd rather that the `Tag` model not use the default `uuid` column for uniquely identifying your tags and instead use the name you could do:

```
class Tag
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode

  id_property :name
end
```

That also creates a constraint for the `name` property.